# Python requests Post request data with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send a simple post request to a very simple django server and can't wrap my head around why the post data isn't appearing in the requests post dictionary and instead its in the request body.

Client code:

```
    payload = {'test':'test'}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'text/plain'}
    url = "localhost:8000"
    print json.dumps(payload)
    r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)
```

Server Code:

```
def submit_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          print 'Post: "%s"' % request.POST
          print 'Body: "%s"' % request.body
          return HttpResponse('')
```

What is printed out on the server is:

```
Post: "<QueryDict: {}>"
Body: "{"test": "test"}"
```

I've played around with the headers and sending the data as a straight dictionary and nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `POST` dictionary only contains the form-encoded data that was sent in the body of the request.  The `body` attribute contains the raw body of the request as a string.  Since you are sending json-encoded data it only shows up in the raw `body` attribute and not in `POST`.

Check out more info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

Try form-encoded data and you should see the values in the `POST` dict as well:

```
payload = {'test':'test'}
url = "localhost:8000"
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: I tried that and it was giving me the same thing. Is there anything grossly wrong with just reading it out of the body and processing it from there? Thanks!

Comment: If you are communicating with the server via json, reading the content out of the body attribute is the canonical method I believe.  It's what I've done in the past. :)

Answer (score 2):

Specifying a user-agent in the headers should enable Django to interpret the raw data of the body and to correctly populate the POST dictionary. The following should work:

```
payload = {'test': 'test'}
url = "http://localhost:8000"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I know, this comment is late, but this should be the correct solution because that's the only working method!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove 'Content-type' from headers and use default one which is 'multipart/form-data'

```
response = client.post(
    '/some_url/',
    data={'post_key': 'some_value'},
    # content_type='application/json'
)
```

If you uncomment 'content_type' data will be only in request.body